# Why did L'Rell agree to help Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

Ash Tyler was supposed to be

> dead as far as the Klingons knew.

In season 2 finale, Ash was on the same Klingon battleship with L'Rell when he brought them to help Discovery

This would reveal L'Rell's lies and compromise her position as

> head of Klingon Empire

and

> safety of their son.

Why did L'Rell agree to help discovery when there was so much at stake?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it was easy, but the implications are

1. There was more at stake here than L'Rell's future as chancellor
2. L'Rell had to have picked people she could trust or they would have blown the cover about what really happened to Discovery
3. Tyler doesn't stick around after the battle, returning to Earth. It's quite possible only the bridge crew of L'rell's ship knew he was there.

Since we don't know what happened afterward, it's quite possible L'Rell paid a political price for that.

Comment: I think I want to ask, why did L'Rell agree when there was so much at stake.

Comment: The broader thing here is that L'Rell is "doing the right thing" despite any potential cost. They never enumerate that (likely because of pacing), but that's how I saw it, especially when Tyler returns to Earth and takes over Section 31 (a super secret organization, which is ideal to hide Tyler).